# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource- angular 5

Tags: javascript, spring, angular, rest, angular5

I am using angular 5 and trying to run the following web service

```
 getMethod() {
let headers = new Headers();
headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE');
headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');

headers.append("Authorization", "Basic " + btoa("username:password"));
headers.append("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

const params = new HttpParams({
  fromObject: {
    'startDateTime': '28-04-2018 00:00:00',
    'endDateTime': '28-04-2018 00:00:00',
  }
});
return this.http.get("https://localhost:8443/test?" + params, options).map(
  (response: Response) => {
    const data = response.json();
    return data;
  }
);
```

}

and every time I got the following error

```
Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 403.
```

I have used a workaround to solve this (installing chrome plugin) but it won't work on production so I need a solution because I have tried many recommendation but without any good results, what I need that (1- sending username and password using basic authentication, 2- sending params, 3- solve cross-origin issue)

Comment: You need to configure CORS with Spring backend.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add headers `Access-Control-Allow-Origin, -Methods, -Headers` to server response - so to backend code (not frontend angular code) !

Comment: What about http interceptors ?

Comment: The serwer must allow CORS request - not browser (except plugins workaround - because the browser block CORS request when serwer nod give proper response - and plugins can change this behavioru)

Comment: Okay, I will but do you think that I am sending the params in right ways also the basic authentication credentials

Comment: It depends of authentication mechanism used in your backend - but this is separate topic - good for new question in stack-overflow

Comment: "strict-transport-security": "max-age=31536000 ; includeSubDomains",
  "x-content-type-options": "nosniff",
  "date": "Thu, 03 May 2018 21:23:04 GMT",
  "transfer-encoding": "chunked",
  "access-control-allow-methods": "POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE",
  "content-type": "application/json;charset=UTF-8",
  "access-control-allow-origin": "*",
  "allow": "POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE",
  "cache-control": "private",
  "access-control-allow-headers": "authorization",
  "x-xss-protection": "1; mode=block",
  "x-application-context": "application:Test:8443",

Comment: it is my backend header and still the issue

Comment: the issue now when I add the authentication in header     headersValue.append("Authorization", "Basic " + btoa("username:password"));
    headersValue.append("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"); it fail to load

Comment: what is the error message? Also add to 'access-control-allow-headers' the 'Content-Type' and other headers if You use them (I don't remember is case sensitive or not)

Answer (score 0):

try this below:

```
headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');

headers.append('Accept', 'text/plain');
```

And in backend add this:

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *'); 
header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true'); 
header('Cache-Control: no-cache');
header('Pragma: no-cache');
header('Content-Type: text/plain');
```

Comment: thanks, but how can I send the username and password with basic authentication am I using the right way ?

Comment: headers.append("Authorization", "Basic " + btoa("username:password"));
headers.append("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");